# Finding the number of different ordered quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ of complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, contest-math

Find the number of different ordered quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ of complex numbers such that:

$$a^2=1$$

$$b^3=1$$

$$c^4=1$$

$$d^6=1$$

$$a+b+c+d=0$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**: $b$ and $d$ are the only ones that can have irrational imaginary parts, and as such, must have opposite imaginary parts if either of them has a non-zero imaginary part. Also, $a=\pm1$, and you should be able to conclude that we need $c=\pm1$ as well, for the last equation to be satisfied.

Comment: This is a problem posed on Brilliant. I request that discussion be closed for a week. - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master

Comment: The question has been unlocked, @Calvin. Hopefully it's all clear.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If a quadrilateral is formed by 4 sides of equal length, then there is a pair of sides which are translates of each other, and another pair of sides which are translates of each other.

Hence, $a+b+c+d = 0$ implies that $a+b = 0 $ or $a+c = 0$ or $a+d = 0$.

This also shows how to deal with the more general problem, when the exponents are not just 2, 3, 4, 6, which allow for small case checking.